# trying to applying DRY principle to model methods in django

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

I have these two methods that are identical except in name and one variable, and it really bugs me, but no matter what I do, I can't figure out how make it so that I just pass a variable into a method in django. These are the two methods, I can post the model if it's needed but I'm fairly sure all the info that is needed is in here, but for clarity, the two model fields are 'launch', 'staff_trials' and 'published' all three are just dates, all other variables are created in the method:

```
@property
def progress_launch(self):
    timeline = self.launch - self.published.date()
    current = self.launch - datetime.now().date()
    if timeline < current:
        percentage == 100
    else:
        percentage = 100 - round((current/timeline) * 100)
    min_bar = 1
    max_bar = 100
    if percentage is not None:
        if percentage < min_bar:
             return min_bar
        elif percentage > max_bar:
            return percentage
    else:
        percentage = max_bar
        return percentage

@property
def progress_trials(self):
    timeline = self.staff_trials - self.published.date()
    current = self.staff_trials - datetime.now().date()
    if timeline < current:
        percentage == 100
    else:
        percentage = 100 - round((current/timeline) * 100)
    min_bar = 1
    max_bar = 100
    if percentage is not None:
        if percentage < min_bar:
            return min_bar
        elif percentage > max_bar:
            return percentage
    else:
        percentage = max_bar
        return percentage
```

I tried to do this:

```
def progress_launch(self):    
    return percent(trials)

def progress_trials(self):
    return percent(launch)


def percent(_progress)
    timeline = _progress - self.published.date()
    current = _progress - datetime.now().date()
    if timeline < current:
        percentage == 100
    else:
        percentage = 100 - round((current/timeline) * 100)
    min_bar = 1
    max_bar = 100
    if percentage is not None:
        if percentage < min_bar:
            return min_bar
        elif percentage > max_bar:
            return percentage
    else:
        percentage = max_bar
        return percentage
```

But of course it didn't work. The two methods work fine, it just looks terrible and this particular model is getting rather large as it is. I appreciate this is more likely an OOP issue (Which is why I started to learn django in the first place, to learn OOP), as that is where I am struggling still unfortunately. Any help in getting this code refactored in a better way would be very much appreciated. I can't post any of the error messages as there were too many of them, but they were all about variables not being defined.

Answer (score 2):

Just check what model you got using `isinstance` and use an appropriate field:

```
@property
def progress(self):
    if isinstance(self, LaunchModel):
        start = self.launch
    else:
        start = self.staff_trials
    timeline = start - self.published.date()
    current = start - datetime.now().date()
    # ... etc
```

You can condense this into a single line:

```
start = self.launch if isinstance(self, LaunchModel) else self.staff_trials
```